# Effect of inavriance under rotations of center on random vecotr

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables defined on the same probability space. We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that the law of the random vector $(X,Y)$ is invariant under rotations of center $(0,0)$

IS $X ∼ Y$? And if so why exactly?